# Omnetpp .ned file default value of parameter

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to get familiar with Omnetpp, so I'm doing the TicToc example. But there I found a point I do not understand: Why does the default value of limit not work? Limit is always set to 5, only if I set it to an other value like I did it in Toc5.

Here my log from Txc5::initialize

```
Initializing module Tictoc5, stage 0
Tictoc5.tic: Initializing module Tictoc5.tic, stage 0
Tictoc5.tic: limit is 10 
Tictoc5.tic: tic's counter is set to 10
Tictoc5.tic: Sending initial message
Tictoc5.toc: Initializing module Tictoc5.toc, stage 0
Tictoc5.toc: limit is 5 
Tictoc5.toc: toc's counter is set to 5
```

Here you can see, tic's counter was set to 10, this is ok, but toc's counter is to 5.
I do not understand why its not set to 20, like I have said in `int limit = default(20);`

I have tictoc5.ned:

```
simple Txc5
{
parameters:
    bool sendMsgOnInit = default(false);
    int limit = default(20);
    @display("i=block/routing");
gates:
    input in;
    output out;
}

simple Tic5 extends Txc5
{
parameters:
    @display("i=,cyan");
    sendMsgOnInit = true;
    limit = 10;
}

simple Toc5 extends Txc5 
{
parameters:
    @display("i=,gold");
}

network Tictoc5 
{
submodules:
    tic: Tic5;
    toc: Toc5;

connections:
    tic.out --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> toc.in;
    tic.in <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- toc.out;
}
```

and I have txc5.cc

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>


class Txc5 : public cSimpleModule
{
private:
    int counter;

  protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
};

Define_Module(Txc5);

void Txc5::initialize()
{
    counter = par("limit");
    EV << "limit is " << (int)par("limit") << " \n";
    EV << getName() << "'s counter is set to " << counter << "\n";
    if (par("sendMsgOnInit").boolValue() == true)
    {
        // The `ev' object works like `cout' in C++.
        EV << "Sending initial message\n";
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMsg");
        send(msg, "out");
    }
}

void Txc5::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    counter--;
    if(counter == 0) {
        EV << getName() << "'s counter reached zero, deleting message \n";

    } else {
        EV << getName() << "'s counter is " << counter << "\n";
        EV << "Received message `" << msg->getName() << "', sending it out again\n";
        send(msg, "out");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of parameter is taken from NED provided that there is no matched entry for this parameter in `omnetpp.ini` file (and the parameter isn't *hardcoded* - explanation later). In `omnetpp.ini` for `Tictoc5` example there is following entry: 
 `**.limit = 5` 
Therefore for `Toc5` limit is equal to 5.
However, in definition of `Tic5` in NED line: 
`limit = 10` 
means that the value of limit parameter is *hardcoded* to 10. And according to [OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec126) *hardcoded* parameter:

- cannot be overwritten by value from `omnetpp.ini` 
  file
- doesn't take default value anymore